# Drupal 7, after moving the site from development to production, now when editing a node there is no content in the editing page

Tags: drupal-7

**Drupal 7**, after moving the site from development to production, now when editing a node there is no content in the editing fields Summary or Body nor dose the **CKEditor** work. The only thing I have done is move the files from a subfolder to the root, still using the same data-base. What am I doing or not doing?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to see if permissions have followed (directories and files) and cache were cleared (VERY IMPORTANT)

Comment: Thanks, I'v done all the permissions and file permissions, reinstalled the module and library, to no avail. Even when CKEditor is not installed I still don't see content in any of the text fields.

Comment: do you see those fields in the content type field list ?